# set an environment for development and production but how to access it from other components when calling APIs in react?

Tags: reactjs

I created Environment for both development and production and now I want to access it from other components while calling APIs.

#### Below is the code of environment.js

```
    let BASE_URL = "http://localhost:5000"

     if(process.env.REACT_APP_ENV==="development"){
 BASE_URL = "localhost:5000"
      }

     if(process.env.REACT_APP_ENV === "production"){
 BASE_URL = "http://10.244.25.30:5000/"
      }

      export {BASE_URL};
```

Now I have other components from where I need to call apis and based on the environment whether it is development or production mode.
signup.js code :
I want to call api inside fetch.

```
    fetch("http://10.244.25.30:5000/api/signup", {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(obj),
     })
```

Comment: just import {BASE_URL} and use template strings `${BASE_URL}/api/signup`

Comment: @JohnSnow Thank you for your help,  its working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your solution you should do something like:

```js
const env = require('../environment.js');

fetch(`${env}/api/signup`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(obj),
     })
```

If you are using Create-React-App the better solution is to use `.env` files as documented [here](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables)

Comment: I prefer `.env` approach.

Comment: I don't understand the replationship between using .env and create-react-app. You can use .env regardless

Answer (score 0):

Usually, I create two env files for development and production.
For example: `.env.production` and `.env.development`
If I want to work in Production mode, I just need to change the env file name as `.env`.